# Async code only seems works only when a breakpoint is inserted

Tags: c#, asynchronous, breakpoints

I have the following C# code:

```
var response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
response.Content.CopyToAsync(stream);
System.Console.WriteLine(stream.Length);
```

When I insert a breakpoint before the first statement and then continue the program, the code works fine and over 4 MB of data gets stored in the stream.

But if I run the program without any breakpoints or inserting the breakpoint after the after the first statement shown above, the code runs but no data or only 4 KB of data gets stored in the stream.

Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Edit:
Here is what I am trying to do in my program. I use couple of HttpClient.PostAsync requests to get a uri to download a wav file. Then I want to download the wav file into a memory stream. I don't know of any other ways to do this yet.

Comment: You are not waiting for `response.Content.CopyToAsync(stream);` to complete. Use `await` here. Try to avoid `.Result` as it is a blocking operation

Comment: First, you should be using await.  so `var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);` as well as with to the copy `await response.Content.CopyToAsync(stream);`

Comment: How is this async? You have the . Result behind the method. Maybe I miss something?

Comment: @PeterBons I read somewhere that if we use `.Result`, it just renders the method as synchronous, i.e. the program waits until the method returns, and that is what I want here

Comment: But be aware that that can lead to deadlocks. Why do you want that anyway?

Comment: @PeterBons but if there are no deadlocks, it should perform synchronously, right?

Comment: correct, but you still need to (a)wait for the call to `response.Content.CopyToAsync(stream)` to complete

Comment: @PeterBons I tried `var response2 = Task.Run(async () => { return await client.GetAsync(exportURL); }).Result;` but I still don't get the correct result

Comment: It is not the client.GetAsync, it is the call to `response.Content.CopyToAsync(stream);`. Change it to `response.Content.CopyToAsync(stream).Wait();`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are basically messing the flow of `async` and `await`.

The async call will be waited to complete and recapture the task when you use await keyword.

The mentioned code does not clarify whether you are using the async signature in your method or not. Let me clarify the solution for you

**Possible solution 1:**

```
public async Task XYZFunction()
{
  var response = await client.GetAsync(uri); //we are waiting for the request to be completed
  MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
  await response.Content.CopyToAsync(stream); //The call will wait until the request is completed
  System.Console.WriteLine(stream.Length);
}
```

**Possible solution 2:**

```
public void XYZFunction()
{
  var response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result; //we are running the awaitable task to complete and share the result with us first. It is a blocking call
  MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
  response.Content.CopyToAsync(stream).Result; //same goes here
  System.Console.WriteLine(stream.Length);
}
```